# How to download xls file by ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, xls, vraptor

I'm doing a direct download xls via Ajax and VRaptor, VRaptor makes your paper straight and provides the file as code below:

```
public Download geraExcel() {
 File arquivo = //generate file 
 return new FileDownload(file, "MyFile.xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel", true);
}
```

The problem is to receive this file in the success of ajax, I have a code that does this and it works perfectly for txt, the problem is that the xls opens corrupted and I'm a long time researching solutions to get around, all were unsuccessful, the continuing file corrupted. If anyone knows another way to make it work I thank you. Ajax.success following code:

```
success: function(response, status, xhr) {
    // check for a filename
    var filename = "";
    var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
    if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
        var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
        var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
        if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
    }

    var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
    var blob = new Blob([response], { type: type });

    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
        // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        if (filename) {
            // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            // safari doesn't support this yet
            if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {                
                window.location = downloadUrl;
            } else {
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();

                //Here is the problem, the original is about 15k,  
                // but the download file is about 26K

            }
        } else {                    
            window.location = downloadUrl;
        }

        setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
    }
}
```

Comment: `//generate file`? Are you generating a XLS file or a CSV/HTML and just setting the content-type to open in Excel?

Comment: I'm generating a file xls. Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: You can generate a HTML table and set content to `application/vnd.ms-excel` and it will open in Excel just fine. But you will get a "this file might be corrupt" message.

Comment: It's not ideal, because I've done this generation in java and do not want to redo it